# Django : How to convert pdf file object to image using pdf2image?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a epaper web app, in which admin can upload file in pdf format and which is converted to image while rendering the page from client side. I have tried pdf2image but getting error something like this :

```
PDFPageCountError at /city_list
Unable to get page count.
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '['/media/pdf/Akola/2020/04/24/page01.pdf']': No such file or directory.
```

here is  my code:

models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
    cityid =models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField( max_length=50)
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
# file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
ab = instance.date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
return 'pdf/{0}/{1}/{2}'.format(instance.city.name,ab, filename)

class DailyFeed(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date =models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    page1  = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    page2 = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path) 
    page3 = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

views.py:

```
def city(request):
    city_list = City.objects.all()

    daily = DailyFeed.objects.filter(date=timezone.now().date()).filter(city__name = "Akola")
    ab = [pdfurl.page1.url for pdfurl in daily ]
    path = r'{}'.format(ab)
    a = str(path)
    pages = convert_from_path('{}'.format(a), 200)
    for pdf in pages:
        pdf.save('{}.jpg'.format(a.name[:-4]), 'JPEG')
    return render (request,'main.html',{'city_list':city_list,'page':pdf})
```

urls.py

```
re_path(r'^city_list',views.city,name='city'),
```

I am have not getting where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use path instead of url. URL is not where the file is, but how the browser can access it

```
[pdfurl.page1.url for pdfurl in daily ]
```

to

```
[pdfurl.page1.path for pdfurl in daily ]
```

Comment: still getting error = Unable to get page count.
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '['C:\\django_project\\MP_webapp\\media\\pdf\\Akola\\2020\\04\\24\\page01.pdf']': Invalid argument.

Comment: are you sure the file is a valid pdf? And also it returns an argument error, check the actual call that you are making to the converter.

Comment: Yes. I am having  files in that folder . I have uploaded them again but still same error

Comment: is the file a valid pdf- can you open it in pdf viewer? Also check the permissions of the file.

Comment: yes i can open them. Is there any other way to convert pdf object to image in django ? other than pdf2image?

Comment: try passing the file as a variable and not as array: page = convert_from_path(pdfurl.page1.path, 200)